# Find the key word in the text file then pick the value next to it

Tags: matlab, parsing

I have a large non-homogeneous text file. And I need find the key words in the text then pick the value next to the key words. Here is one part of this text file:

```
  LAW NUMBER ............... =    45.54553
  LAW TYPE:
  152
   Geomaterial_2 - solid PHASE                                
  ELASTIC CONSTITUTIVE LAW FOR SOLID ELEMENTS
  AT CONSTANT TEMPERATURE
  USE OF EFFECTIVE STRESSES. ISOL =    1
  NUMBER OF SUBINTERVALS.... NINTV=    1
  YOUNG'S MODULUS .......... =   0.200000E+08
  POISSON'S RATIO .......... =   0.300000    
  SPECIFIC MASS AS A MATERIAL LAW,
  RHO ...................... =    2670.00    
  LAW TYPE: 
  171
   Geomaterial_2 - liquid PHASE                               
  WATER-AIR SEEPAGE- VAPOR -THERMAL COUPLED
  CONSTITUTIVE LAW FOR SOLID ELEMENTS
  ISOTROPIC CASE IANI =     0
  FORMULATION INDEX FOR krw IKW  =     0
  FORMULATION INDEX FOR kra IKA  =     0
```

I need the full value of 'LAW NUMBER' with the decimal values, similarly if the value for 'LAW NUMBER' was negative. How can I do this?

I have the following script:

```
% Import the whole file at once

fid  = fopen('test.txt','r');
text = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','');
text = text{1};
fid  = fclose(fid);
% Parse LAW NUMBER

LW = regexp(text,'LAW NUMBER[\s\.=]+(\d+)','tokens');
LW = [LW{:}];
LW = str2double([LW{:}]).';
% Parse LAW TYPE
```

Comment: When asking a question about code, it's always helpful if you include a tag for the language that you're using. Can you [edit] to do so? Thanks.

Comment: I did similar work lately. I used regex to select the specific line, then I used array.split by a space string(" "), and used the result to get the string I wanted.